# How can I retrieve data by year like pic using flutter and hive db?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

[image]

How can I retrieve data by year like pic using flutter and hive db?
My class is like this:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Pulse extends HiveObject {
@HiveField(0)
DateTime dateTime;

@HiveField(2)
int pulseRate;
@HiveField(3)
int saturation;
@HiveField(4)
bool isOpen;

Pulse({
required this.dateTime,
required this.pulseRate,
required this.saturation,
this.isOpen = false,
    });
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

since there is no box example, I will say that if we have a box likt this:

```
Hive.box<Pulse>('pulseBox));
```

then you can get `Pulse` object values which have a specific year in their DateTime with the `where` like this:

```
Hive.box<Pulse>('pulseBox)).values.where((pulseElement) => pulseElement.dateTime.year == 2022);
```

This will return a `List<Pulse>` of all elements inside the box which have a `DateTime` with the 2022 year.

Comment: Thanks I found specific  year data now .can you tell me how can I generate user year . like upload year 2020, 2021,2022.

Comment: I didn't what you're requesting, can you clarify

Comment: I added some images.I want to make this kind of functionality. How can I do that

Comment: you mean you want to know how t store data with that DateTime with the year to Hive ?